# Get-AzureDeployment not returning expected result

Tags: powershell, azure-rm

Im trying to get all the Azure cloud services that are deployed, just looking for the service name and its label field in particular. I'm using the cmdlet Get-AzureDeployment but it is not returning the desired result.

**cmdlet used:**
 $getResultForMyService = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName "myservicelistedincloudservice" -Slot "Production"

The **output** im getting is

```
  *>Get-AzureDeployment : ResourceNotFound: No deployments were found.
  OperationID : 'a********************074'
    At line:1 char:9
+ $Data = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName myservicelistedincloudservice" -Slot "Prod …
+ CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureDeployment], ComputeCloudException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.HostedServices.GetAzureDeploymentCommand*
```

I tried to make sure that the context is using the correct subscription prior to running the Get-AzureDeployment cmdlet. But this was also not helpful.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> set-azurermcontext -SubscriptionName MySubscription

FYI, I've installed the latest version and prior to executing the above cmdlet I have imported the Azure module as well. FYI, below is my PS version details:

Also I followed the install instructions for servicemanagement module from MS docs link but that doesn't help either - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/servicemanagement/install-azure-ps?view=azuresmps-4.0.0

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.1
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Any pointers to get the cloud service listed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got this working. I followed this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77d36a5e-9c98-4003-bc52-367c00156b40/how-to-change-subscription?forum=azurescripting

As this Get-AzureDeployment cmdlet is related to ASM i used non rm cmdlets, here are the cmdlets & steps i followed:

Step 1: 
    **Add-AzureAccount**

Initially I got this error "No subscriptions are associated with the logged in account in Azure Service Management (RDFE)." and 
i got rid of this after adding myself to co-administrator role even though i was having the Owner role in Portal for my subscription.

Step 2: 
    **Get-AzureSubscription**

This should list all subscriptions and also it says which one is the default(IsDefault) and current(IsCurrent) subscription. Please note the subscription which has the IsCurrent = True or IsDefault = True. Please note that these 2 parameters are deprecated and both will have same value for any subscription, in other words you cannot set one subscription with IsCurrent = True and other subscription with IsDefault = True.

Step 3:
    **Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName mysubscription**

This cmdlet is not needed when your mysubscription is the current subscription(IsCurrent = True), otherwise run this cmdlet to set mysubscription as your current subscription.

Step 4:
    **Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName "myservicelistedincloudservice" -Slot "Production"**

If this service(myservicelistedincloudservice) belongs to mysubscription subscription then this will return the result as it has been set the IsCurrent = True, otherwise you will see that "ResourceNotFound: No deployments were found." error.

We need to make sure the 4 cmdlets are executed in the same order as above otherwise you wont know what's causing the issue. Hope this will help someone.

Comment: well, you could probably mention you dont know what you are doing at all, i could have told you all of that

Comment: yeah may be I could have told that i'm new to powershell, sure I will mention it going forward, and anyway thanks for your time and trying to help me out.

Comment: @4c74356b41 why did not you tell then?

Comment: @mv_05 I faced with the same problem. Even if I have owner role in cloud services, Add-AzureAccount did not work and gave me, "No subscriptions are associated with the logged in account in Azure Service Management (RDFE)" . Then I saw your solution which is add your account to co-administrator role, so I added myself and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Gald that it helped you. Sorry seeing this post after a long time :). Would you mind marking this as accepted answer :)